# Trouble while trying to pass data from JS to PHP using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So I'm building a string with a JavaScript function and then I want to pass it to PHP.

This is my JavaScript block

```
<script>
        function passVal(){

            var strUrl = buildStringUrl(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2);
            var data = {
                fn: strUrl,
                str: "testString"
            };

            $.post("home.php", data);
        }
        passVal();

</script>
```

And when I try to recover that data from POST like this:

```
<?php 
       $reqUrl  = $_POST['fn'];
       echo $reqUrl;
?>
```

I get a PHP error on

```
Notice: Undefined index: fn
```

But fn is supposed to be already defined in POST. What am I missing?

EDIT: When I check the Network tab on chrome you can see the string under the name of "fn" on the Form Data section as you can see on the next [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpdqK.jpg). The string is a URL.

Comment: please check the content of strUrl, if it is undefined it isn't added to the post.

Comment: can you do `var_dump($_POST);` and `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));`

Comment: @Djaevel it's a string, I've already checked it.

Comment: @AgamBanga It's empty. The output is "array (size=0) empty" :(

Comment: and what about the `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));`?

Comment: Do you ever go to `home.php` without going through the AJAX call?

Comment: @AgamBanga It shows "path\home.php:163:string '' (length=0)"

Comment: @Barmar Yes, everything's on the home.php file, I even make some DB queries before doing this.

Comment: you can check the `Network` tab in chrome & see if the ajax is going through with the data

Comment: Are you getting that error when you make the AJAX call, or when you just open the page normally in the browser? When you open it in the browser, the parameters haven't been sent yet.

Comment: @AgamBanga I edited my question so you can see what's in the network tab.

Comment: @SergioYáñezJiménez In the network tab, you can tell us what `Content-Type` is set to under `Request Headers` for the ajax call?

Comment: @rideron89 it says Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

Comment: try to urlencode fn value. Also make sure you're posting to the correct php page as well as make sure POST is enabled on your sever.

Comment: Are you making *multiple* requests to `home.php`? One with Ajax (which actually works) and one through some other method (which doesn't)?

Answer (score -1):

You might need to encode the URL you are passing through. Try this:

```
function passVal() {

    var strUrl = buildStringUrl(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2);
    var data = {
        fn: encodeURIComponent(strUrl),
        str: "testString"
    };

    $.post("home.php", data);
}
passVal();
```

Comment: You definitely do not need to do that. jQuery will do that for you. Doing it manually will double encode it.

Answer (score -2):

Problem.

```
<script>
    function passVal(){
        ...
    }
    passVal();
</script>
```

passVal() needs an event. Probably it works on initialisation (once) but you look at a later time.

```
<a onClick="passVal();">click</a>
```

What happens then?

Kind regards